# Move, rotate and resize edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, rotation, resize, ontouchlistener

I need to move, rotate and resize edittext based on user's touch gestures.

**Here is what I am doing**. 
1. Listen for ACTION_DOWN event to detect single finger touch and then use that for movement.

2. Listen for ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, and get the index count to detect two finger touch and then use ACTION_MOVE for rotation.
3. I need to make resize work such that only the width gets decreased on resize by touch.

**Problem I am facing**
Movement is working perfectly fine. But when I apply rotation using the ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, rotation goes all sorts of haywire. Any suggestions on how to make the view movement and rotation work together?

Here is the code for touchListener I have applied

```
tvMain.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    moving = true;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                    Log.d("ActionPointerIndex", "" + event.getActionIndex());
                    int index = event.getActionIndex();
                    moving = false;

                    //FOR ROTATION DETAILS
                    xc = tvMain.getWidth() / 2;
                    yc = tvMain.getHeight() / 2;

                    x_ = event.getX();
                    y_ = event.getY();

                    Log.d("currentAnglePD", ": " + x_ + "," + y_);
                    if (index == 1) {
                        rotate = true;
                        mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x_ - xc, yc - y_));
                        moving = false;
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    if (moving) {
                        leftBound = rootView.getX();
                        topBound = rootView.getY();
                        rightBound = rootView.getX() + 1280;
                        bottomBound = rootView.getY() + 618;


                        x = event.getRawX() - tvMain.getWidth() / 2;
                        y = event.getRawY() - tvMain.getHeight();

                        dx = Float.valueOf(rootView.getWidth() - tvMain.getWidth());
                        dy = Float.valueOf(rootView.getHeight() - tvMain.getHeight());

                        bottomBound_ = tvMain.getY() + tvMain.getHeight();
                        rightBound_ = tvMain.getX() + tvMain.getWidth();

                        if (x >= leftBound && y >= topBound && x <= dx && y <= dy) {
                            tvMain.setX(x);
                            tvMain.setY(y);
                        }
                    }

                    if (rotate) {

                        Log.d("currentAngleMove", ": " + x_ + "," + y_);

                        mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle;
                        mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x_ - event.getX(), yc - event.getY()));
                        animate(mPrevAngle, mCurrAngle, 0);
                        System.out.println(mCurrAngle);
                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    rotate = false;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    rotate = false;
                    moving = false;
                    //tvMain.clearAnimation();
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Movement is working fine, but once I move the view, rotation goes haywire, and it does not rotate along its center. Once I stop rotating, the view stops listening for any more touch gestures.

Comment: please provide code for help.

Comment: @Kriti Please check the edit